# Allow IgnoreQueryFilters followed by select query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, soft-delete

I am using ef core V2.1 with soft-delete.

I tried to fetch a student, with all his milestones record (include, some which were deleted), using the IgnoreQueryFilters() method.

But while I could do this:

```
applicationDbContex.Students
.IgnoreQueryFilters().Include("Milestones.Type")
.Where(...)
.ToArray();
```

When I tried to add a select statment after the where clause, It did not fetch the deleted milestones.

```
applicationDbContex.Students
     .IgnoreQueryFilters().Include("Milestones.Type").ToArray();         
     .Where(...)
     .Select(s => new {
         PersonalNumber = s.PersonalNumber,
         Milestones = s.Milestones 
     })
```

Here is the simplified models i am using:

```
public class Student {

    public ICollection<Milestone > Milestones {get; set;}
}

public class Milestone {
    ..
    public MilestoneType type {get; set;}
    ..
}

public class MileStoneType {
    ..
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ..
}
```

Any suggestions of what might be the problem?

EDIT:

I wish to state, that I use 'UseLazyLoadingProxies()' in startup.cs

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
                options.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
                    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
            );
```

It seems, that inorder to select query to work, I have to fetch a complete object , for instance the code works only, if I use the following code before:

```
 applicationDbContext.Soldiers.IgnoreQueryFilters()
            .Include("Milestones.Type").Load();
```

Comment: Seems to work correctly in EF Core 2.2.4. Might be a bug that have been fixed.

Comment: My guess: When you call `IgnoreQueryFilters()` after `Select()`, you're no longer invoking it in the context of `IQueryable<T>` where `T` is your entity type (that is known to EF) but rather your `T` is now some anonymous type created in the previous lambda. All in all, try to call `IgnoreQueryFilters()` before the call to `Select()`.

Comment: Tried to call the IgnoreQueryFilters before, it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you must call ignoreQueryFilter befor where and select

```cs
applicationDbContex.Students.IgnoreQueryFilters().Where(...)
     .Select(s => new {
         PersonalNumber = s.PersonalNumber,
         Milestones = s.Milestones 
     })
     .Include("Milestones.Type").ToArray();
```

and Include is useless when you use Select!